# ValueError on the Flask library

Tags: python, html, flask

im trying to get data from python to html

PYTHON
app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/html.html')
def test_route():
   data=["tony","mika"]
   return render_template('html.html', data=data)
```

HTML
html.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% for item in data %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

it should display the names ,but i dont know why it is not working

Comment: wouldn't the single item from the array just be `item`, and only have the one reference (since it's a for loop) ?

Comment: do you have a sample error message with a line number? does it include a stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake is you have not imported render_template:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/html.html')
def test_route():
   data=["tony","mika"]
   return render_template('html.html', data=data)

app.run()
```

Now make some edits in html.html files which should be in templates folder.

Directory structure

```
app.py
templates--> html.html
```

html.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% for item in data %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

now run your code and check for the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/html.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing body to

> `<body> {% for item in data %} <tr> <td>{{item}}</td> </tr> {% endfor %} </body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should look like this:

```
<tr>
  {% for item in data %}
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Since you're iterating over the data array, `item` represents a single item from the array.